# 3d points from stereo camera

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a stereo camera setup.
I have calibrated in using opencv stereoCalibrate, with an RMS error of 0.674634.

I find 2d points on both images using findContours and moments.

I triangulate using this code:

http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/01/04/simple-triangulation-with-opencv-from-harley-zisserman-w-code/

With the P1 and P2 Mats from the extrinsics.xml.

And the resulting points are extremely incorrect. (i expect a chair, i get a line).

My questions are:

Am I using the correct part of the extrinsics calculation?

Do I need to find correspondences somehow in both images? That would make sense, but I am not sure how to go about it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: One of the comments below insists that following is correct implementation of triangulation ("...properly utilizing the cv::triangulatePoints function, see the function") - https://gist.github.com/royshil/7087bc2560c581d443bc#file-simpleadhoctracker-cpp-L93